# Progress .Net open client - When to use ProDataSet instead of Temp-Tables?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I'm working on a .Net open client to work with Progress Appserver. I've a set of 5 Input-Output static temp-tables in an order/detail scenario. I've read that a Prodataset can also be used to achieve the same.

Is there a benefit of using a Prodataset over using static temp-tables in this scenario? Where one should use a Prodataset instead of temp tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ProDataSet is a convenient way to organize a group of related temp-tables.  You seem to have a group of related temp-tables so you would potentially benefit from dealing with them as a unit rather than individually.

Actually, even if you only have a single TT it is beneficial to wrap it into a PDS - there are lots of features that you get with a PDS like change tracking and error status that you don't get with a plain old TT.  Plus you get a standardized interface regardless.  And it costs nothing extra to do it.

Comment: This. Because of what Tom explained, a PDS also makes for a great wildcard parameter. It can contain one temp-table or many, it can be passed around as a single object, and you can parse and work it as you wish using some dynamic coding.

Comment: Full disclosure:  Mike Fechner was looking over my shoulder suggesting improvements as I wrote that ;)

Comment: @TomBascom Thanks a bunch, very well explained. I've gone through the PDS manual from Progress. Do you have a reference to some resource that I could go through to see PDS interaction with a .Net open client?